# Pronunciation of doctor

Tags: pronunciation, spelling

Why is `doctor` pronounced as `doc-ter`? I would expect it to be pronounced the way it looks: `doc-tor`. Is this true for all words ending with `tor`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some general principles of English pronunciation, as I see them, that apply here:

1. Unstressed vowels tend to be reduced to a [schwa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwa), no matter how they're written.
2. As a result, while "-er" is probably the "normal" way to write the unstressed ending of "doctor" (and "bursar", "mother", "elixir", "sulphur"), it's really just something that can happen to any vowel.
3. Some dialects or some individuals will always pronounce things differently. There are some that *will* pronounce the -or ending unreduced. (In general, I mean; in specific cases where the syllable is being emphasised, anyone could pronounce the -or unreduced.)
4. After scanning a list of -tor words, it does seem to me that **yes**, all of them would normally be pronounced with a reduced vowel.

These are broad and simplified statements (for example, phoneticians will probably argue the exact relation between "reduced vowel" and a true schwa), but I hope they help.